# Using JQuery with SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, spfx, jquery-ui, accordion

Reading this tread ([Add jQuery in Client Web part (SPFX)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240963/add-jquery-in-client-web-part-spfx)) I'm going to open a new question with another problem.

I am also following the accordion tutorial from Microsoft docs and trying to customize it using jQuery functions:
[Add jQueryUI Accordion to your SharePoint client-side web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part).

Example works fine by following the steps.

Problems come when I want to rewrite (or replace) styles of the default classes to custom colors to my SharePoint Site Theme.

I've read API docs from here:
[Accordion Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/accordion/#option-classes).

I added a new class in root level of `JQueryWebPart.module.scss` file (hard-coded red is only for reference and testing purposes).

CSS:

```css
.myAccordionHeaderActive{
    background: red;
}
```

And just added the following line after accordion creation:

Typescript:

```
//Line like shown in the example
jQuery('.accordion', this.domElement).accordion(accordionOptions);
//My New Line
jQuery('.accordion', this.domElement).accordion("option", "classes.ui-accordion-header", styles.myAccordionHeaderActive);
```

I think it should work but new red background does not appear.

Obviously, before to come here to ask for help I tried many other ways to do that with this call, following API docs, but couldn't get that.

Typescript:

```
jQuery('.accordion',this.domElement).accordion(accordionOptions).accordion("option", "classes", "ui-accordion-header : ${styles.summarAccordionHeaderActive}");
jQuery('.accordion',this.domElement).accordion("option", "classes", "ui-accordion-header : ${styles.summarAccordionHeaderActive}");
```

None of them work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your TS code looks correct:

```
jQuery('.accordion', this.domElement).accordion("option", "classes.ui-accordion-header", styles.myAccordionHeaderActive);
```

Try using 'important' in your CSS class definition

```
.myAccordionHeaderActive{
    background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried but did not work. 
Thanks for the idea.
I think this is a an issue related on how copiler imports and executes the project.
I think my custom class is not available at the moment of the execution of the "option".
Neither works even embedding custom class in the domElement

Answer (score 0):

I have found a tricky solution.
It's ugly and dirty, but works.

What I have done is rewrite JQuery CSS classes right before render the accordion in the html DOM.

TypeScript: (Original example from MS Docs)

```
public render(): void {
  this.domElement.innerHTML = MyAccordionTemplate.templateHtml;

  const accordionOptions: JQueryUI.AccordionOptions = {
    animate: true,
    collapsible: false,
    icons: {
      header: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e',
      activeHeader: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s'
    }
  };

  jQuery('.accordion', this.domElement).accordion(accordionOptions);
}
```

TypeScript: (My additions)

```
public render(): void {
  //rewrite some accordion css classes properties
  this.domElement.innerHTML = `<style type="text/css">
        .ui-state-default{
          background: none;
        }
        .ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
        .ui-state-default .ui-icon{
          background-image: none;
        }

        .ui-accordion-header-active{
          background: #0078d4;
          color: white;
        }

      </style>`;
  //Concatenate original example
  this.domElement.innerHTML += MyAccordionTemplate.templateHtml;

  const accordionOptions: JQueryUI.AccordionOptions = {
    animate: true,
    collapsible: false,
    icons: {
      header: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e',
      activeHeader: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s'
    }
  };

  jQuery('.accordion', this.domElement).accordion(accordionOptions);
}
```

Hope someone else find the correct use of JQuery Library or realizes what is the issue cause.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a better workaround so I can apply theme colors to accordion. Which is what I wanted to do when I opened this thread.

Instead of writing the style directly in the DOM.innerhtml, I've create a new CSS file (not SCSS, just CSS) and set colors using theme tokens.

AccordionMyStyles.css (for example)

```css
.ui-state-default{
    background: none;
    color: white;
}

.ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
.ui-state-default .ui-icon{
  background-image: none;
}

.ui-accordion-header{
  background-color: "[theme: themePrimary, default: #0078d4]"; 
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ui-accordion-header-active {
  background-color: "[theme: themeTertiary, default: #71afe5]"; 
  color: #222222;
}
```

In .ts WebPart main file, import AccordionMyStyles.css file using require

```
require('./AccordionMyStyles.css');
```

And that worked for me and covered my needs. Hope it to be useful to someone else.